# How to delete native IOS app using Xamarin UITest

Tags: ios, xamarin.uitest

I am very new to and have just started using Xamarin UI Test for automation testing of native iOS apps. Could anyone advice or point me to any documentation on how to delete the app (from UI) and reinstall it (from a URL).
Thanks for any help.

K

Comment: What do you need this for? Tests shouldn't rely on being run on a fresh install.

Comment: Thanks Losiowaty. The reason is that we have few features like First time login - our application has no logout or reset and once I login the userdata is saved. I cannot delete the app data. So reinstall is my only option. Any other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Well, ideally each test should prepare the environment for itself. Besides, if the app doesn't have such mechanisms why cannot the tests have them? :)

Comment: Hmm. You are right. I will think about more about it and get back.

Answer (score 0):

For UITest aach test run will delete the app from your device and re-install it so that it starts from a known state. Anything inside a test attribute like bellow is considered its own test:

```
    [Test]
    public void RenameTodo()
    { 
      //test
    }
```